# Java to Word Document Table Color

Tags: java, java2word

Hi I can write a table into a word document as the code below... I wonder how do you add table cell background colour?

```
    IDocument myDoc = new Document2004();
    //myDoc.addEle(BreakLine.times(1).create()); 
    Table tbl = new Table();

    tbl.addTableEle(TableEle.TH, "Jira Number", "Description","asd","ee");


    myDoc.addEle(tbl);
```

Comment: Is this the library you're using? - https://github.com/leonardoanalista/java2word

Comment: @ChrisMartin hi there. yeah I am using that library.

Comment: Does anyone knows if the table is able to be shaded with colours?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

Try to instantiate a TableV2 rather than Table.

take a look at the example:

http://java2word.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/huge-ms-word-documents-with-java2word.html

you'll have to do something like this "withStyle().bgColor("00FFFF")" in your fluent interface code.

cheers
Leonardo Correa